# Prove that : There exists a vector $x$ such that $Mx = x$ , where $M$ is a Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, determinant, stochastic-matrices

Here's a proof that I found which looks pretty simple but I can't understand the last step.
(A Markov matrix is a square matrix whose columns sum to one;
$I$ is an identity matrix;
$M^T$ and $I^T$ refer to the transpose matrices)

[image]

Comment: A quick search returns a few similar posts: [Is it true that for any square row-stochastic matrix one of the eigenvalues is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60081), [Eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$  of a stochastic matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1838770), [Proof that the largest eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix is $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40320), and probably many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinants of a square matrix and its transpose are identical. This means that their characteristic polynomials are identical, which in turn means that they have the same eigenvalues. When you left-multiply a matrix by a vector, the result is a linear combination of the matrix rows. In particular, left-multiplying by a vector of all $1$s sums the rows of the matrix. Each column of a Markov matrix sums to $1$, therefore $\mathbf 1^TM = \mathbf 1^T$. Transposing, we see that $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector of $M^T$ with eigenvalue $1$, therefore $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ and there must by definition exist some non-zero vector $\mathbf x$ such that $M\mathbf x=\mathbf x$.

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the notations, as you only made a part of the proof available, where the notations are not defined. In fact, I probably use the reverse setup. So long story short, this might not ne a good answer, and there is no way to tell until you make the problem clear.

But if by Markov matrix you mean a non-negative square matrix whose columns (?) add up to 1, then the reason $M^T-I$ has an eigenvector is that the all $1$ vector is trivially a good example.

Comment: Im so sorry but I didn't really understand that, how do we know that the all 1 vector is an eigenvector?

Comment: Could you provide more details before asking more questions, please? Is my guess about the notations correct?

Comment: I edited the question to add notations before I posted that comment